# How to translate my sitemap page name?

Tags: magento-1.9, sitemaps

Where can I translate my Magento shop sitemap? I want to change name of pages and also some general text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it either by creating another static block setting it to be displayed in the store view that you want and rewrite it to your language. Or you can go to app/design/locale/ locate the language file that you want and add the translation in there.